# how to use single server for both development, prodcution and QA using svn

Tags: svn

i am web developer and new to SVN. I have to use one single to both PROD and DEV process .Normally i will create two servers one for DEV site another for PROD site. Once our development process was complete, i will send the DEV site link to client. If the client approved the changes , then i will move those changes to PROD server for viewing to public.Some cases we forget to update some codes in PROD server from dev server.

please guide me , how to use svn here to avoid these issues and everything in single server.

Answer (score 1):

The default usage in such cases is to use branches for that purpose. For example. Starting development on trunk after finished development make tag for release-1.0.0 and if you need something which needed to be changed in production for it just create a branch based on the tag release-1.0.0 . This can be continued for as many releases as you like.

Comment: +1, in most places with sane change management release tags are made immutable (via repository pre-commit hooks)

Comment: May be misunderstand the comment. Of course are release tags immutable. So what's the problem?

Comment: tags are just folders in subversion, to make them immutable one must create a respective pre-commit hook. I personally find it convenient to have only subset of tags (say starting from "rel_") immutable

Comment: I know that tags are just folder but from my point of view they are immutable of course not from the technical point of view. I see the point.